# Possible / Recommended to write event driven app in Go?

Tags: multithreading, go, event-handling, worker

I am designing an app to manage RabbitMQ workers given certain rules. For example:

- Maintain a minimum number of workers
- Spawn up to N max number of workers if queue grows beyond M tasks
- Kill workers older than X minutes

I originally thought of writing it in Go because it is compiled & I could simply compile the app to the target OS & daemonize it. However, my concept design involves having a loop that gathers data every Y seconds & passes it through a decision engine. The engine would then raise events that would be listened to by other goroutines to either spawn or kill workers.

I've found the [Emission](https://github.com/chuckpreslar/emission) library which would acommodate this, but I read a comment somewhere that it might not be thread safe. Honestly, my knowledge of Go & threaded programming are not sufficient to properly evaluate if this library would accomplish what I need or if this is even possible in Go.

I could write this very quickly in NodeJS and even get it compiled using [nexe](https://github.com/crcn/nexe). However, I wanted to learn a new language, I liked the targeted compilation in Go, and that it can be multi-threaded beyond the goroutines themselves.

Is this possible or am I trying to shoehorn something into Go that it wasn't designed to do? Would it be better to accomplish the same goals differently or to just use a different language all together?

Comment: No, this sounds like the perfect usecase for go.

Comment: Thank you, @inf . would you suggest using emission or is there a different way to raise events?

Comment: Spawn goroutines and send events over channels.

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

Comment: http://nesv.github.io/golang/2014/02/25/worker-queues-in-go.html

Comment: One of you guys wants to add this as an answer? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not seen Emission library before which could work very neatly to send different messages to your workers. This could also be achieved by using channels which would be a more flexible implementation but also more cumbersome if you do not know the language.

I would certainly read on channels but be very careful as broadcasting through channels is not straightforward. Take a look at this example (https://rogpeppe.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/concurrent-idioms-1-broadcasting-values-in-go-with-linked-channels/)

Overall I would take a look at Tunny (https://github.com/Jeffail/tunny) to manage workers it already has most of the implementation done for you.

Comment: You're right about channels not being straightforward. I had issue with the blocking for long running process initially & then noticed I needed to do it in loops. It finally clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Go is a very good language for i/o intensive apps, particularly if they involve messaging. However, your use case appears to concern *managing* RabbitMQ rather than *messaging*. For this purpose, Go has rather less that makes it stand out in its favour.

You might want to stand back and consider the system as a whole. How much of it needs to use RabbitMQ? If that is an open question, you might find that the lightweight goroutines and channels are a useful tool. Just maybe, you can implement parts of your system that use MQ directly in a Go program. But if you try this, remember that the fundamental CSP model is of *synchronous / blocking message passing*, quite different from the MQ model. Buffering, queueing, asynchronous operations etc are layered on top of this primitive behaviour.

If your intention really is just managing RabbitMQ, maybe take a look at the [rabbitmq-http](https://github.com/smallfish/rabbitmq-http) project to help you make up your mind.

Comment: eventually the app will manage more than just RabbitMQ workers & the workers need to be language agnostic. This app is work & we don't have many programmers that can write go.

Comment: Fair enough - Go is easy to learn but it's unreasonable and risky to demand that colleagues learn quickly on the job.